# How to allow IIS website user to execute .cmd program

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-command-prompt

I have a situation where I need to execute a .cmd program on my IIS website.
It's a 3rd party program to validate and transfer files, so I'm not able to choose otherwise.

I do this by starting the program in a new process programmatically.

Taking this approach with a .exe file works perfectly. I receive the standard output from the program. But this is just not the case when I try to do the same with the .cmd file. No standard output is received.

The code works perfectly on my local computer, so I figure that the problem lies within the IIS configuration. Probably user or file restrictions.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

**EDIT** Here is C# code I use.

```
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"export\foo.cmd"; 
    //replacing foo.cmd with foo.exe works
    info.UseShellExecute = false; 
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
    using (Process process = Process.Start(info)) 
    { 
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) 
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you attempting to execute the CMD script as a CGI application? What do you mean, specifically, when you say "I do this by starting the program in a new process programmatically"?

Comment: I have tried 2 things. One is to start a new process with a pointer to the .cmd program. The other one is to start the cmd.exe program with a argument command pointer to the .cmd program. E.g. /c "path-to-file/foo.cmd". Wise people tell me these two approaches are exactly the same.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I have actually posted a question on SO originally, since my first assumption was that the problem originated in the code. But being that the code works locally, I thought that the issue could relate to the IIS settings somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I have posted my findings on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575386/foo-cmd-wont-output-lines-in-process-on-website).

It actually turned out to be a IIS AppPool user issue, so posting the question here was not completely hopeless afterall.